# Network information displayed in Linux Console

Tags: networking, fedora

I have a Fedora 10. NetworkManager is stopped. Network is configured with a static ip address.

On my screen i have this : [image]

How do i disabled that network information output ? I don't see it on SSH, only the main console.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically console output is specified in `/etc/syslog.conf`.  Fedora 8 and newer uses rsyslog, which would be `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.  Looks like netfilter (iptables is the userland client) activity to me.

Comment: I don't have syslog.conf and I didn't find any service with a name that look like netfilter.

Comment: I played with my iptables with the rule : iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-level 4

I even tried level 1, but it still continue to log everything. I restarted rsyslog also, i really don't want to disable the log.

edit: it stopped with a log level 7. I thought that 0 emerg, 1 alert, 2 crit, 3 err, 4 warning, 5 notice, 6 info, 7 debug. So isn't it supposed to log more and more ?

Comment: The log level is identifying the "type" of log.  Daemons output logs using a level, as you listed above.  How the different levels are handled are specified in the rsyslog.conf.  The iptables rule is specifying what log level is associated with the messages.

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want all kernel messages to console, you can cut it in /etc/sysctl.conf
by adding `kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7`

Use it by `sysctl -p` command.
It works at least on Debian and Ubuntu, so why not in Fedora